# What biplane is this a model of?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

[image]

What biplane is this a model of?

Comment: Thank you for sticking to one per post. I have made the title as specific as possible.

Comment: As noted in @MichaelTracy's post below, this is the night-fighter or "Comic" variant of the Camel. In the picture in Michael's post you can see the two Lewis guns attached to the upper wing spars and the rectangular cut-out ala the Snipe - but both the model picture and the picture in Tracy's post show a straight upper wing and 5 degrees dihedral in the lower wing. So the model is a night-fighter-variant Camel which has had its upper-wing Lewis guns removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plane is probably modelled after both a Sopwith Snipe and a Sopwith Camel. Look at the cutout of the wing above the pilot's seat. It's rectangular as on the [Snipe](https://www.rafmuseum.org.uk/blog/sopwith-snipe-dragon/), not a semicircle as on the [Camel](https://www.rafmuseum.org.uk/blog/camels-dolphins/). The engine looks like a Camel's however.

So, this model is possibly a hybrid of two famous World War I British fighter planes.

It could also be a specially modified Camel according to @Michael Tracy (except the painting scheme does not match the one on the picture he provides).

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the 6th picture in [this Camel link](https://www.rafmuseum.org.uk/blog/camels-dolphins/), you’ll see the exact same rectangular cut-out.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The plane is a [Sopwith Camel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopwith_Camel). It was a British fighter in service from 1917 to 1920. There were 5490 built, of which only 8 survive, but many replicas are on static display and a few are even airworthy.

[image: Sopwith Camel]
<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopwith_Camel#/media/File:RAF_Sopwith_Camel.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Build an Airfix model of one many decades ago :-).

Comment: I thought the Sopwith Camel looked like [this](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=qTuSWqSgAoGmjwTEpImIBg&q=snoopy+sopwith+camel&oq=snoopy+sop&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.0.0l5.2091178.2096878..2098019...2....104.834.10j1..........1..mobile-gws-wiz-hp.....3..35i39j0i131i155j0i131j0i20i264j0i131i20i264j0i22i30.VG2QgX3KdkE%3D#imgrc=-4WIJq6P5EA4bM:)

Answer (score 4):

As for the specific plane it appears to be a rough approximation of a **Sopwith Camel** from No. 209 Squadron RAF–most likely Roy Brown's *B7270*.

[image]
<sub>Source: Valder137 [CC BY 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0), via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ASopwith_Camel_F.1_A_Roy_Brown_RSideFront_CFM_7Oct2011_(15325166215).jpg)</sub>

Capt. Brown was officially credited by the RAF for shooting down Manfred von Richthofen, the "Red Baron", but modern historians suggest it was likely Australian anti-aircraft fire from the ground.